# Using postcss in node to modify string of css

Tags: node.js, postcss

I have a javascript string of css:

```
let style = '' +
  'body {display: flex;} ' +
  'body {background: red;}' +
  '#id5 {color: blue;}' +
  '$id7 {color: green;}' +
  '#id5 {color: yellow;}';
```

I'm trying to import postcss in my project so that I can use combine duplicate selectors: https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-combine-duplicated-selectors

```
const postcss = require('postcss-js');
const postcsscombine = require('postcss-combine-duplicated-selectors');

let combiner = postcss.sync([ postcsscombine ]);
let newStyle = combiner(style);

console.log(newStyle);
```

The desired output would be something like:

```
'body {display: flex; background: red;} #id5 {color: yellow} #id7 {color: green;}'
```

Actual output

```
{ '0': 'b',
  '1': 'o',
  '2': 'd',
  '3': 'y',
  '4': ' ',
  '5': '{',
  '6': 'd',
  ...
  '100': 'l',
  '101': 'o',
  '102': 'w',
  '103': ';',
  '104': '}' }
```

It looks like postcss handles incoming style objects rather than strings. Is there a way to fix this up to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PostCSS to work a string of CSS, just do the following:

```
const postcss = require('postcss');
const postcsscombine = require('postcss-combine-duplicated-selectors');

let style = 'body {display: flex;}, body {background: red;}, #id5 {color: blue;}, $id7 {color: green;}, #id5 {color: yellow;}';

postcss([postcsscombine])
  .process(style , {from: 'undefined'})
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.css);
  });
```

You need to set the `from` property of the process options object to 'undefined'. Also, some plugins are asynchronous so it's better to use the promise interface.